# How to implement data layer in React Application for Adobe analytics (adobe launch) ?

Tags: reactjs, adobe-analytics, data-layer

I have to build data layer in my react application but I am only able to find articles implementing data layer in VanillaJS. And my company is not using google analytics but Adobe Launch instead.

Comment: your question is vague, you should put people more in context so can help you.

Comment: I am not sure how is data layer added in a react component because in Javascript it is added between the script tags and is easily read. I tried finding online resource for the same but could not find.

Comment: React is javascript, I think you have your understanding about concept wrong, maybe you need to clarify that data layer is a term of adobe analytics? I don't think with this description of your problem someone could help you.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kt/integration/using/launch-reference-architecture-guides.html
It's not clear what your specific question is, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the adobe analytics documentation [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kt/integration/using/launch-reference-architecture-guides.html).
There is in ReactJS with Redux Implementation with Launch by Adobe section